# Why did my app get rejected because "Multitasking apps may only use background"?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I tested my app in the background by setting the alarm and watching a video, and my alarm was correctly ringing when I was watching the video.

Even when I removed my app from the background the alarm was ringing. Now I wonder if I correct understood Apple's reply.
Can any one decode the reply?

> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This
>   behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for audio in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but no audible content is
>   played when the application is in the background. While your intention
>   may have been to provide this functionality, at the time of review, we
>   were not able to play background audio for your app.
>
> As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide:
>
> "This key is intended for use by applications that provide audible
>   content to the user while in the background, such as music-player or
>   streaming-audio applications."
>
> Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible content to the
>   user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting
>   from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What don't you understand about it?  It is very clear that you gave a UIBackgroundMode of "audio" but didn't play any audio in the background.

Comment: Ok, but if you read my first para, i said the audio was playing in the background, is this what they are mentioning or something else is what the question. whether i have tested correctly?

Comment: You said "an alarm was ringing".  This is not the same as background audio.  Background audio means that you are playing music or something continuously.  You don't need it for just an alarm (Look into Local Push Notifications)

Comment: borrrden,this is the step i did 1) Set the alarm from my app 2)came out from my alarm app (clicked the home button) 3)now watching the video 4) When the alarm time came, Using a local notification my app played a music (in parallel i could watch the video aswell), then i clicked the notification and my app opened and correctly played the alarm ring. So now where is the problem thats what i am not able to understand?? Really confused, this is first app feel frustrated..

Comment: You are not allowed to use an alarm sound of longer than 30 seconds (unless you are Apple).  See here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1 for details on how to play an alarm sound.  The audio background mode is not appropriate for this (Apple expects you to be streaming audio in the background for the entire duration).

Comment: Thanks for the link, Yes My local notification alarm sound is less than 30 secs , once my alarm is opened, inside the alarm another sound would be played. So u mean to say the background mode is not necessary for this?

Comment: That is exactly right, and that is why your app was rejected.  Having a background mode active and not using it as intended wastes system resources (and Apple doesn't like that)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **Background Modes** from **capabilities** and there check **audio** and **background fetch** . Then your app is able to access all audio streaming from the background.