# How to run iOS app in background

Tags: ios

I found that iphone apps do not run in the background except for certain cases like voip, music player and GPS apps. I found [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/charge-alert-lite/id403024766?mt=8) in the app store, it does not belong to any of these categories, runs in the background and provides sound alerts in the background.

How is this possible?

Comment: Offtopic. Ask the app vendor how'd they get is past certification, or ask Apple support if some kind of waiver process exists.

Comment: If I had to guess they register it as a music player which allows it to continue operations in the background.

Comment: They have a useless option of getting sound alert every minute, i think that's what allowed them to use `audio` background mode approved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646034/why-did-my-app-get-rejected-because-multitasking-apps-may-only-use-background, this thread says that app was rejected even when it played an alarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps like this usually do workarounds based on things you mentioned:

1. playing "silence.wav" (= acting as music player)
2. using GPS

**UPDATE:** From Info.plist of this aforementioned app:

```
UIBackgroundModes
    audio
```

Using Xcode [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22):

> audio | The app plays audible content in the background.

Therefore this app uses first approach (i.e. it mimics music player) to run in the background.

Comment: I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646034/why-did-my-app-get-rejected-because-multitasking-apps-may-only-use-background, where apple does not allow apps even if they play some alert at regular intervals. They need music to be playing continuously like in a music player app.

Comment: ok, I'll check this app for you... anyway, Apple review result depends on reviewer and there were examples of apps that do prohibited things (for example private API's)