# start AVAudioSession & AVAudioPlayer in Background using didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, avaudioplayer, alarm, avaudiosession

Can I play `AVAudioPlayer` when in the app is in background using silent push notification ?

My current implementation is like this :

1. Send silent push notification
2. `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` is triggered
   and create the session then play mp3 from there.

The issue is that the session seems to be taken away when your app is not active for quite a time (like one night) and `AVAudioSession` is not given if you request it from background mode, so the `AVAudioPlayer` won't play the mp3.

I'm developing an alarm app for emergency things, so the app need to play an audible sound even if the phone is muted and locked.

Anyone has been encountered any similar implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The solution in your case would be to use "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key, which effectively tells the system that the app's main purpose is to play music in the background: "The app plays audible content to the user or records audio while in the background". See this for details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

However, it seems that Apple will reject "alarm apps" that use this approach as alarms do not play constantly and do not qualify as "audio apps". See this answer: [Why did my app get rejected because "Multitasking apps may only use background"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646034/why-did-my-app-get-rejected-because-multitasking-apps-may-only-use-background).

You can try to "play" silence most of the time, but they will reject it either.

To summarize, you can implement this Alarm App technically, by using silent push notifications and UIBackgroundModes key, but this method is against Apple review policies.

Comment: That being said, let me know if you find a solution. Most of alarm apps I am looking at use local notifications, but they are useless since alarm needs to ring even if Silent switch or "Do not disturb" modes are on.

Comment: hi ivan, technically this is indeed possible, the problem is if i stop sending silent push for some time (like 1 night), the moment i send the silent push again, the app won't play the mp3 file. To make the app play the mp3 again, i have to bring the app to foreground, send the silent push, let the app play the mp3 in foreground, then the app will be able to play the mp3 again when silent push arrive in background mode. About review policies, i'll give it a try since my app is not for public.